# `which nologin` is not working over SSH, while `which false` — works

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to know where is `nologin` located on a remote machine via SSH. So, I run `ssh pi@raspberrypi-1.local 'which nologin'`. However, the command returns non-zero. But running which false is ok.

Note the `1!` in the output which denotes last command execution result in my command prompt:

```
$ ssh pi@192.168.100.57 'which nologin'
1! $ ssh pi@192.168.100.57 'which false'
/bin/false
$
```

If I login to that host and execute `which nologin` I get the result: `/usr/sbin/nologin`.

Why is `which nologin` is not working over SSH?

Comment: I guess `ssh pi@192.168.100.57 'bash -l -c "which nologin"'` will do what you expected.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, indeed, the issue seems to be the non-login shell when executing command via SSH that does not append `/usr/sbin` to `PATH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The $PATH might get set several times during the login process:

1. By sshd itself, either built-in or from /etc/login.defs.
2. By PAM modules (though usually not).
3. By the shell's "profile" scripts (/etc/profile, ~/.profile).

In your case, the path set in step 1 doesn't have /sbin or /usr/sbin, but the path set in step 3 does.

2) Depending on the shell, it might behave differently in "batch" (single command) mode than it does in "interactive" mode.

Bash, in particular, does not read /etc/profile or ~/.profile when it is being started non-interactively. In other words, it just skips the configuration in step 3, which would normally add /usr/sbin to the command path.

(Bash's behavior is actually distro-dependent: some Linux distributions enable the compile-time option to make it read profile scripts in all modes.)

A somewhat acceptable workaround:

```
ssh user@host ". /etc/profile; . ~/.profile; which nologin"
```